# If $X=[x_{ij}]_{n \times n}$ then how prove $X^n=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $n\in \mathbb N$ and $A_1,A_2,..,A_n$ be arbitrary sets. Now define $X=[x_{ij}]_{n \times n}$ where
$$x_{ij}=
\begin{cases}
1 ,  & \text{$A_i$$\subsetneq$}A_j \\
0 , & \text{otherwise}  \\
\end{cases}.$$
How do you prove $X^n=0$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *What* is element of $\mathbb{N}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** by iteration of the formula $(XY)_{ij}=\sum_{k=1}^nx_{ik}y_{kj}$ for the coefficients of a matrix product, we have 
$$
(X^n)_{ij}=\sum_{1\leq i_1,\ldots,i_{n-1}\leq n}x_{ii_1}x_{i_1i_2}\cdots x_{i_{n-1}j}.
$$

> For a term of this sum to be nonzero, we need $x_{ii_1}=x_{i_1i_2}=\ldots=x_{i_{n-1}j}=1$, i.e. $A_{i}\subsetneq A_{i_1}\subsetneq \ldots\subsetneq A_{i_{n-1}}\subsetneq A_j$. Can this happen? How many sets in the chain?

Comment: :thanks  $\Large\color{green}{✓}$

Comment: @MaisamHedyelloo That's a nice typesetting trick you have here!

Comment: :yeah i will copy it it nice idea i will use it

Answer (score 2):

If you know some Graph Theory:

Define a digraph the following way: the vertices are $A_1,A_2,..., A_n$. The arcs:
Put an arc $A_i \rightarrow A_j$ if and only if $A_i\subsetneq A_j$.

Your matrix $X$ is exactly the incidence matrix of this digraph. Since the digraph contains no directed cycles, it contains no directed path of length $n$. Thus $X^n=0$.

Comment: :why digraph contains no directed cycles ?

Comment: @MaisamHedyelloo Because if $A_{i_1} \to A_{i_2} \to ... \to A_{i_k}\to A_{i_1}$ is a directed cycle, you get $A_{i_1} \subsetneq A_{i_2} \subsetneq ... \subsetneq A_{i_k}\subsetneq A_{i_1}$. In particular $A_{i_1} \subsetneq A_{i_1}$.

Comment: :$\Large\color{red}{+1}$:nice approach thanks